# Get value from JSON on conditional base

Tags: plsql

how to get the value from a specific attribute on the basis of value check of another attribute value in oracle 12c. Below is the JSON

```
{
   "Operational_Cost21":[
      {
         "Input1":"20000",
         "Operational_cost23":"Diesel"
      },
      {
         "Input1":"5000",
         "Operational_cost23":"Maintenance"
      },
      {
         "Input1":"20000",
         "Operational_cost23":"Other Variable Cost"
      },
      {
         "Input1":"100000",
         "Operational_cost23":"Driver Salary"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the value of input value where operational_cost23 = 'Driver Salary'

expected Value = 100000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first add this constraint into your table.`CONSTRAINT ensure_json2 CHECK (SAMP IS JSON)`. Then you can use `JSON_TABLE` function.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6287)

```
DROP TABLE TESTTABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ;

CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE
   (
    SAMP CLOB
    CONSTRAINT ensure_json2 CHECK (SAMP IS JSON));
   
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
  VALUES (
          '{ "Operational_Cost21": [
    {
      "Input1": "20000",
      "Operational_cost23": "Diesel"
    },
    {
      "Input1": "5000",
      "Operational_cost23": "Maintenance"
    },
    {
      "Input1": "20000",
      "Operational_cost23": "Other Variable Cost"
    },
    {
      "Input1": "100000",
      "Operational_cost23": "Driver Salary"
    }
  ]
}');

SELECT J.Input1,J.Operational_cost23 
       FROM TESTTABLE,
       JSON_TABLE(SAMP,'$.Operational_Cost21[*]' COLUMNS 
       Input1 VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Input1',
       Operational_cost23 VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Operational_cost23'
       ) J 
where operational_cost23 = 'Driver Salary'
```